# SSL Post Request to Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, post, ssl

I need to develop a web-based service on Google Appengine (Python 2.7) that involves the sending of sensitive data from a third-party website over to my site (preferably through SSL).  Say that my url is https://example.appspot.com, and I want the third-party site http://example.com to send two values through a POST request, one is `username` and the other is `password`, to https://example.appspot.com/receiverhandler. This receiver handler is `class ReceiverHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler)`. My question is basically: how can I send this POST data through an SSL connection? I'm not entirely familiar with the SSL protocol, so I have no idea where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using urlfetch, just send it to the SSL-secured url: https://example.appspot.com/receiverhandler

This gives great explanation of how to do it, using POST params (payload):

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/

Comment: Unfortunately example.com isn't necessarily appengine-based. I forgot to mention example.appspot.com is HTTPS, sorry.

Comment: You could have the 3rd party site POST to the https://appspot address using ajax, for example.